# Install Java EE 6

Tags: jakarta-ee, installation, ibm-rad

I'm trying to install the Java Enterprise Edition 6 on my workstation.  I downloaded the installer from the [Sun website](http://java.sun.com/javaee/downloads/index.jsp). Whenever I get to the option in the installer "JDK Selection" I'm told to manually select a JDK.  I gave it my path (`C:\IBM\rad7\jdk\`), and was told it is invalid.  What do I need to do to successfully install JEE6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to install and use the [Sun JDK](http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/widget/jdk6.jsp) instead.

Comment: If you really need JEE6, This answer is great. Otherwise use JEE5.

Comment: Keep in mind that Java EE is an abstract specification. Sun Glassfish (also known as Sun Java Application Server) is one of the concrete implementations. The JEE6 download link provided at Sun.com is in fact just the Glassfish AS (along with a bunch of documentation, tutorials, examples, and optionally also Netbeans). It indeed requires the Sun JDK. But for other (yet to come) JEE6 (web profile) implementations like Tomcat 7, Websphere 8(?), JBoss AS 6, etcetera I think you don't necessarily need the Sun JDK since they ships with their own compiler (at least, they currently do).

Answer (score 0):

I used version 5 instead of version 6.  Rad 7.X does not come with the version 6 JDK.